# The multi-part identifier "x" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get the error `The multi-part identifier "inserted.PlaceId" could not be bound.`
What is the problem?

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateVotes
    ON [dbo].[VoteLog]
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentVotesNo int
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @CurrentVotesNo = (SELECT Votes from dbo.[Places] where Id = inserted.PlaceId)

    if ( select Vote from inserted ) = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.[Places]
            SET Votes = @CurrentVotesNo, @CurrentVotesNo=@CurrentVotesNo+1
            from [dbo].[Places]
            join inserted
            on [dbo].[Places].Id = inserted.PlaceId
        END
    else if ( select Vote from inserted ) = -1
        BEGIN
            update dbo.[Places]
            SET Votes = @CurrentVotesNo, @CurrentVotesNo=@CurrentVotesNo-1
            from [dbo].[Places]
            join inserted
            on [dbo].[Places].Id = inserted.PlaceId
        END
    END
```

I also tried to with join, like this: `SET @CurrentVotesNo = (SELECT Votes from dbo.[Places] p join dbo.VoteLog on p.Id = inserted.PlaceId )`

Comment: `(SELECT Votes from dbo.[Places] where Id = inserted.PlaceId)`.. you forget a join here?  is that really your only error?

Comment: @JamieD77 I also tried : `SET @CurrentVotesNo = (SELECT Votes from dbo.[Places] p join dbo.VoteLog on p.Id = inserted.PlaceId )` with no success

Comment: You have to join INSERTED table in subquery to make this work.

Comment: Your trigger will raise an error if you ever insert or update more then one row in a single statement. This is a very common mistake made by people with little experience with triggers. This row, for example - `if ( select Vote from inserted ) = 1` will raise a *subquery returned more then one value...* error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled you are right, this is my first trigger attempt

Comment: I've been there myself a few years back :-) It was a pain to find the source if that error, but at least I'll never forget it :-)